# Горизонтальный скролл элементов по клику

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть вот такой код

```js
< script >
  var scroll;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".scroll-container ul > li").each(function() {
    $(this).detach().appendTo($(".scroll-container"));
  });
  $(".scroll-container").css("margin", "0px 0px 0px -" + String(parseInt($(".scroll-container").css("width")) / 2) + "px");
});

function sliderDirection(d) {
  clearTimeout(scroll);
  if (d === "left") {
    slideLeft();
  }
  if (d === "right") {
    slideRight();
  }
}

function slideLeft() {
  clearTimeout(scroll);
  $(".scroll-container").css({
    "left": "50%",
    "transition": "all 0s linear"
  });
  $(".scroll-container").css({
    "left": String(parseInt($(".scroll-container").css("left")) - 260) + "px",
    "transition": "all 0.5s linear"
  });
}

function slideRight() {
  clearTimeout(scroll);
  $(".scroll-container").css({
    "left": "50%",
    "transition": "all 0s linear"
  });
  $(".scroll-container").css({
    "left": String(parseInt($(".scroll-container").css("left")) + 260) + "px",
    "transition": "all 0.5s linear"
  });
}

function moveLeft() {
  $(".scroll-container ul > li").first().detach().appendTo($(".scroll-container"));
  slideLeft();
}

function moveRight() {
  $(".scroll-container ul > li").last().detach().prependTo($(".scroll-container"));
  slideRight();
}

function moveSlider() {
  $(".scroll-container ul > li").first().detach().appendTo($(".scroll-container"));
  slideSlider();
}

<
/script>
```

```css
.scroll-container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding-left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.list-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-container>* {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 275px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 315px;
  padding: 0 0 3rem 0;
}

.list-container>*:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.list-container_item,
.scroll-header {
  color: #000;
}

.list-container_item,
.scroll-header {
  padding-left: 5%;
}

h3.scroll-header {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.list-container_item {
  background-image: url(https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/marker.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 10px 10px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

a.right.slider-control,
a.left.slider-control {
  width: 3%;
  height: 17%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54);
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  top: 40%;
  border: none;
}

a.right.slider-control,
a.left.slider-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
}

a.right.slider-control {
  right: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-container horiz-scroll" id="scroll-feature">
  <a class="left slider-control left-scroll" onclick="sliderDirection('left')" id="left-scroller">
    <img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/left-arrow.png" class="carousel-arrow" alt="Left arrow">

  </a>
  <a class="right slider-control right-scroll" onclick="sliderDirection('right')" id="right-scroller">
    <img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/right-arrow.png" class="carousel-arrow" alt="Left arrow">

  </a>
  <ul class="list-container scroll-images">
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
      <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
      <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Сейчас он не работает вообще, но если бы он работал, то он бы скроллил элементы неправильно, как показано на рисунке ниже: [image: на рисунке ниже]

Помогите пожалуйста исправить неработащий код, чтобы он хорошо скролил горизонтальный текст как в примерах [здесь](https://codepen.io/Clasen00/pen/xPpYXd) и [здесь](https://codepen.io/hippolips/pen/qOrMXR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, сделал вот так

```js
$("#left-scroller").click(function(event){
$('.scroll-container').animate({scrollLeft:'+=1500'},500); 
});
    
    $("#right-scroller").click(function(event){
$('.scroll-container').animate({scrollLeft:'-=1500'},500); 
});
```

```css
.scroll-container {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.list-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    /*  Keep the element in one line */
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*  Not much effect */
    align-items: stretch;
    /*  Make them all the same height */
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    /*  This one makes the trick */
    padding: 0;
}

.list-container > * {
    /*  Target only the first top level children */
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin-right: -0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 275px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 315px;
    padding: 0 0 3rem 0;
    /*  The gap must be in the element definition */
}

.list-container > *:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.list-container_item,
.scroll-header {
    color: #000;
}

.list-container_item,
.scroll-header {
    padding-left: 5%;
}

h3.scroll-header {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.list-container_item {
    background-image: url(https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/marker.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px 10px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

a.right.slider-control,
a.left.slider-control {
    width: 3%;
    height: 17%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54);
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    top: 40%;
    border: none;
}    

a.right.slider-control, a.left.slider-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    z-index: 111;
}

a.right.slider-control {
    right: 0%;
}

.relative {
    position: relative;
}


.list-container:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="relative">
            <a class="left slider-control left-scroll" onclick="sliderDirection('left')" id="left-scroller">
       <img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/left-arrow.png" class="carousel-arrow" alt="Left arrow">
      
    </a>
            <a class="right slider-control right-scroll" onclick="sliderDirection('right')" id="right-scroller">
                    <img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/right-arrow.png" class="carousel-arrow" alt="Left arrow">
                   
                </a>
            <div class="scroll-container horiz-scroll" id="scroll-feature">
                <ul class="list-container scroll-images">
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="https://nadv.ru/_v2/images/defaultimg.png" alt="">
                        <h3 class="scroll-header">lrem</h3>
                        <p class="list-container_item">lrem</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
```